# WiFi frequently drops, suspected driver issue

Tags: fedora, wifi, macintosh, dmesg, broadcom

I'm running a fully up-to-date Fedora on a Macbook Pro. To get WiFi working in the first place, I installed `akmods-wl` as recommended. The WiFi works, but the connection keeps dropping. I've noticed this is especially true when there are several devices on my WiFi (when I'm the only person in the house it's usually OK although it still drops on occasion, when roommates come in with their laptops + their phones, the drop rate increases).

When connection drops it's usually down for 30 seconds-1 minute before reconnecting. In worst cases this happens every couple of minutes. I have another laptop running Fedora and the WiFi is fine on there, even when there are many devices in the network.

My wireless card is `Broadcom BCM4331`:

```
$ lspci | grep Broadcom
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
01:00.1 SD Host controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 02)
```

`iwconfig` on my wireless interface:

```
$ iwconfig wlp2s0 
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"WINDRUSH"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 44:E9:DD:0E:7F:00   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

`dmesg` shows lots of these two errors:

```
...
[11387.414926] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_tx_power : error (-1)
[11507.449435] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : error (-1)
[11507.449440] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_tx_power : error (-1)
[11627.486001] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : error (-1)
[11627.486008] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_tx_power : error (-1)
[11631.113431] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : error (-1)
...
```

Couldn't find any solutions for Fedora regarding this issue. Found some from Arch Wiki and Ubuntu but they didn't work and were also dealing with different versions of the Broadcom wireless card.

*(Even if no one has any clear tips for me, can someone explain what those two errors in `dmesg` mean?)*

Answer (score 0):

Searching for "ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_tx_power : error (-1)" gave me a whole ream of the same question, but it does seem to have a common thread... Kernel version 3.16-3.19 + Broadcom drivers:

(sorry for the links, but its hard to follow the thought-thread without them)

https://bugs.mageia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15893

leads to

https://bugs.mageia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16390

which leads to

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1415880

which apparently has a patch for it.

Answer (score 0):

As broadcom-wifi simple owner,
suffering of similar issue *(I would simply describe them as a general stability issues)*
*From my experience*, I say it is **simply** the current state of their **closed-source driver**,
this means we (the whole community) **unfortunately** cannot fix those issues;
and any tentative will be temporary (until the next Linux kernel version) and partial (mostly device-specific)

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 36 MacBook late 2009

Symptom - wifi randomly droping out

I installed drivers as per
https://www.thetestspecimen.com/posts/broadcom-wifi-modules-fedora/

Symptoms remained

Wifi has become stable since turning off location-services in Gnome Settings
(I believe therein lies a clue)

Comment: Are you sure that it was disabling location services that did the trick? If I recall correctly, it only really prevents Flatpak applications from accessing Geoclue.